# Set vertex of vector<vector<int>> to 0, 0

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a `std::vector<std::vector<int > >` built from a `std::vector<std::string>` read in from a file. I am successful in using it to perform a BFS, however I have one little catch:

How can I set the lower-left corner of the `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` to `(0,0)` before I perform by BFS?

Comment: You can't, each entry has one value, so the "lower left" as you call it (whatever index that may be) can have, at best, the value 0.

Comment: @Donnie Is there a smart way to treat it as though it was the origin? Not necessarily assign it a value of `(0,0)` but for calculating distance?

Comment: Distance doesn't care where the origin is, and you can shift the coordinates just by adding the appropriate offsets when you're done.

Comment: What does "lower-left corner" mean with vector in a vector?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Pretty straight forward I would imagine...if you have a grid that is x,y (i.e. a vector within a vector), it would be the lowest-left position.